# vbscript to read registry keys and its subkeys

Tags: vbscript

I want to change the Source file Server path location in the reg path 
`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products\Product GUID\SourceList\Net\1`   of every client machines,

as we have removed the existing Application server with a new one...We were able to change the old server path to new server path using the "replace" function in vbscript.

```
Set objWS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 

strKeyValue = objWS.RegRead("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products\A7C4EB2D0BDDF2A43BDD35A498E12655\SourceList\Net\1")  

newstrKeyValue = Replace(strKeyValue,"\\INADCSRV11" ,"\\INADCSRV12")

newstrKeyValue2 = Replace (newstrKeyValue ,"SMSPKGC$" ,"SMSPKGP$")


     Const HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT = &H80000000
     strComputer = "."

     Set oReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _ 
                                            strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

     strKeyPath = "Installer\Products\A7C4EB2D0BDDF2A43BDD35A498E12655\SourceList\Net\"
      strValueName = "1"
     strValue = newstrKeyValue2

      oReg.SetExpandedStringValue HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT,strKeyPath,strValueName,strValue
```

but we are stuck in reading the reg values....
Product `GUID` is a variable.First we have to read till that path and then after reading one `GUID`, again we have to read the complete path
`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products\Product GUID\SourceList\Net\1` and then change the server name

Please let me know anyone have encountered any situation like this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm not mistaken and you want to enumerate all the subkeys within a certain key this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322789/search-for-registry-key-in-all-of-the-subkeys-of-a-path/8393466#8393466) from another question shows code that does this.